# Mains electricty flowing back into turned off generator

Tags: electrical

During the recent power outage I operated my change over switch and fed power from a 4Kw Honda Generator into my house supply having first turned the mains isolator switches to OFF.

When mains power came back on I turned the generator off and reset the isolator switches.  Foolishly I forgot to unplug the generator so that mains power flowed into the generator ,nor did I remember to operate the change over switch.  Not surprisingly it will not now start.

QUESTION - What damage  am I likely have done to my generator?

Comment: If you have to unplug your generator to stop the flow, your setup is faulty. If power's also flowing from the generator into the grid during an outage, you better be real concerned about the damage to the utility crews working on the line.

Answer (score 5):

If your generator isolator switch was installed correctly, there would have been no damage at all because no power would have flowed into the generator at all.

The isolator should be setup so that at most one of grid power or generator is connected to the rest of the house. This means that when the isolator switches are in the grid power setting the generator plug is isolated from the house wiring. This can be done in some panels by using a plate that slides to block a certain breaker from turning on when another is on.

If you instead used a suicide cord to backfeed into an outlet then you need to install a proper generator inlet which does do the proper isolation. There is a reason I called it a suicide cord.

The actual damage done to the generator can range from none to blowing the fuse to overheating and melting the wiring. Hard to say for sure from this end of the internet.

Comment: Or destroying the motor by turning it without it expecting it. Generators make excellent motors when backfed. It's called [reverse power](https://marinehack.blogspot.com/2017/07/why-is-reverse-power-motoring-of.html).

Comment: THis is really really bad. Something is wrong with your installation. Post pictures of the panel with the interlock, remove the cover and take pictures of the innards. When utility power was restored, how did  you realize power was being fed TO the generator? It also tells me that's a 2 way street, you might have been feeding power INTO the grid (mains)during the outage which is illegal, dangerous and can kill linemen.  Don't use this again until it's totally sorted out.